# kses v.s. strip_tags

Tags: php

kses (http://sourceforge.net/projects/kses/)  or just strip_tags, which to use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depends very much on your use-case. You can be sure that `strip_tags()` is *much* faster, since it is a builtin function that was written in c. `kses` on the other hand seems to provide more features. So if you don't need more than what `strip_tags()` does, just use the builtin function.

Answer (score 3):

I had a quick look at the kses code. I noticed that:

- it relies on the ‘>’ character not being present in attribute values (which is legal)
- its ‘bad URL protocol’ handler won't filter out things it can't parse, like malformed character references and control characters.

I don't think I'd really trust this.

If you must allow (and filter) HTML, you could try the [htmlpurifier](http://htmlpurifier.org/). I can't vouch for its security either, but it is widely used.

HTML filtering using anything other than a full HTML parser is *hard*. If you can provide any alternative to allowing the user to enter HTML (eg. using a simplified textual markup language), do that instead.

Comment: thank you, bobince. I learn a lot! I use kses just because I only know it, and it's used by wordpress.